# How to do a multiplication between a variable array and a fixed number using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to multiply 10 to a variable obtained from an array list of available C: drive density. However, its failing to "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32"."

Was wondering if anyone has met this issue?

```
$deviceID = 'C:'
$a= Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceId='$deviceID'" | Select-Object Size, FreeSpace, VolumeName, DeviceID, @{n='SizeGb';e={[int]($_.Size/1GB)}}
$aarray= @()
$a| % {$aarray += $_.SizeGb}
$ans = ([int]$aarray * 10)
$ans * 10
```

Comment: Hi @VivekKumarSingh made a mistake, the $i should be 10 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to cast `System.Object[]` to `[int]` (which is not possible) via this line:

```
[int]$aarray * 10
```

You've to index through the array via a `foreach`/`for` loop (or via `ForEach-Object`) and do the multiplication. Also check out Powershells [about_array section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6).

For example:

```
PS C:\> $arrayMultipliedByTen = $aarray | % { $_ * 10 }
PS C:\> $arrayMultipliedByTen
4640
```

Also be aware that a multiplication of array will dump the array values n-times. Example:

```
PS C:\> $arr = 0..1
PS C:\> $arr
0
1
PS C:\> $arr * 2
0
1
0
1
```

What you want is:

```
PS C:\> $arr | % { $_ * 2 }
0
2
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @moerwald thank you.. it was what i was searching for.